# PvBuffer (Pleora SDK) to - > Opencv buffer

Tags: c++, opencv

I have an issue converting (Pleora SDK)PvBuffer  into an Opencv buffer and process the stream.

this is a sample code i found in (Pleora SDK C++ sample codes)

```
while ( !PvKbHit() )
{
    PvBuffer *lBuffer = NULL;
    PvResult lOperationResult;
    PvBufferWriter lBufferWriter;

    // Retrieve next buffer
    PvResult lResult = aStream->RetrieveBuffer( &lBuffer, &lOperationResult, 1000 );
    if ( lResult.IsOK() )
    {
        if ( lOperationResult.IsOK() )
        {
            PvPayloadType lType;

            //
            // We now have a valid buffer. This is where you would typically process the buffer.
            // -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

            lFrameRate->GetValue( lFrameRateVal );
            lBandwidth->GetValue( lBandwidthVal );

            // If the buffer contains an image, display width and height.
            uint32_t lWidth = 0, lHeight = 0;
            lType = lBuffer->GetPayloadType();

            cout << fixed << setprecision( 1 );
            cout << lDoodle[ lDoodleIndex ];
            cout << " BlockID: " << uppercase << hex << setfill( '0' ) << setw( 16 ) << lBuffer->GetBlockID();

            if ( lType == PvPayloadTypeImage )
            {
                // Get image specific buffer interface.
                PvImage *lImage = lBuffer->GetImage();

                // Read width, height.
                lWidth = lBuffer->GetImage()->GetWidth();
                lHeight = lBuffer->GetImage()->GetHeight();



                unsigned char * data = lBuffer->GetImage()->GetDataPointer();

                Mat OpencvImg = Mat(Size(lWidth, lHeight), CV_8UC1, data);

                threshold(OpencvImg, OpencvImg, 100, 255, 0);
```

if you check the last 3 lines , I am trying to convert the buffer into a Mat but without success . I also would like to display the stream as well .

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

I have had some success with the following however this result is really inefficient and I am hoping to find a way to do the conversion that does not involve the intermediate writing to the disk.

```
cv::Mat workImage;
lBuffer->GetImage()->Alloc(lWidth, lHeight, PvPixelBGR8);               
lBufferWriter.Store(lBuffer, "ImageOriginal.bmp", PvBufferFormatBMP);
workImage = cv::imread("ImageOriginal.bmp", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
```

Edit (this worked):

```
cv::Mat workImage;
PvImage* lImage = lBuffer->GetImage();
lImage->Alloc(lWidth, lHeight, PvPixelRGB8);
// Get image data pointer so we can pass it to CV::MAT container
unsigned char *img = lImage->GetDataPointer();
// Copy/convert Pleora Vision image pointer to cv::Mat container
cv::Mat lframe(lHeight, lWidth, CV_8UC3, img, cv::Mat::AUTO_STEP); 
lframe.copyTo(workImage);
```

Comment: cv::Mat workImage;
     PvImage* lImage = lBuffer->GetImage();
     lImage->Alloc(lWidth, lHeight, PvPixelRGB8);
     // Get image data pointer so we can pass it to CV::MAT container
     unsigned char *img = lImage->GetDataPointer();
     // Copy/convert Pleora Vision image pointer to cv::Mat container
     cv::Mat lframe(lHeight, lWidth, CV_8UC3, img, cv::Mat::AUTO_STEP); //orig CV_8UC1
      lframe.copyTo(workImage);

Comment: That worked, sorry for the weird formatting, I don't have much experience on stack overflow